# "who am i" command returns empty prompt

Tags: linux, bash, fedora-25

I am following a book on Linux. One of the first commands is to execute `who am i`. It should return my username. However, it returns an empty prompt.

What am I missing?

I am using Fedora 25.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: `who am i` is actually the same as `who -m` (see https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/who-am-i-command-4175607132#post_message_5718169). You can use `who foo bar`, it will produce the same result. And the result will be different depending on your terminal emulator : some emulators won't return anything (see https://sorami-chi.hateblo.jp/entry/2018/02/18/002530).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write:

```
who am i
```

You're actually passing two parameters ("am" and "i") to the `who` command:

```
:~$ who --help
Usage: who [OPTION]... [ FILE | ARG1 ARG2 ]
```

You want to do (without the spaces; it's a different function):

```
whoami
```

to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I also tried  who -ami and who --am -i, but as you said, thats totally different command.

Comment: Should not be the accepted solution. `who am i` is actually a valid syntax : `who foo bar` is interpreted as `who -m` (see `man who`, and also https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/who-am-i-command-4175607132#post_message_5718169).

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the command from a terminal in Gnome, it does not return information. However, it does show results you if execute it in a `tty` terminal.

Comment: Not true it both works for me. Also a commandis probably not going to check what terminal it is in.